# How to override JS Resource in Magento 2 Checkout

Tags: javascript, checkout, magento-2.0

I am trying to override JS Resource in Magento 2 Checkout. Precisely I want to add code to funktion placeOrder in Magento_Checkout\js\view\payment\default.js

I have tried 'mixins' feature but did not make it work. I am stucked here due to lack of good instruction for Mangeto 2.

Any idea will be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

In `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add this

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/opc-checkout-method':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/opc-checkout-method'
        }
    }
};
```

We can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2

Comment: this is a old way of doing it. This will no longer work.

Comment: @Pathfinder could you share me your new way?

Comment: There is now several variables to override in magento 2.3.
https://i.imgur.com/dfjni14.png

Comment: Is it necessary to specify any <sequence> to make sure the override isn't overridden by something loaded later?